# How to create multiple indexes at once in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch provides [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) api but it only supports `index`, `create`, `delete` and `update` operations over already created indexes. We cannot create multiple new indexes at once.

I have a scenario where my index `settings/mappings` are frequently changing. Currently I have to use `delete all` api and then re-create indexes individually. I have more than 100 indexes with distinct names and settings/mappings. So, rather than deleting and creating each index individually, using a bulk api or similar feature would be alot easier.

Comment: If you use the `index` command all unexisting indexes will be created during the bulk call.

Comment: @Val can I also specify index mappings,settings as well ?

Comment: I suggest you leverage [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) in order to pre-specify how future indexes should be setup, so that when you create the first document, all the correct settings and mappings get applied

Comment: @Val Thanks. So, basically I can apply some common settings/mappings to each index using `index templates`, in case that index is missing. But can I create multiple indexes with full and distinct settings supplied for each one of them ?  Actually that is my requirement.

Comment: I invite you to read the link I gave above, that feature supports exactly your requirement.

Comment: @Val In my case, I will have to create multiple templates because indexes are very distinct. But the problem remains same. If the settings/mappings of many indexes changes later and I have to change/re-create templates individually again, what is the point of using it ? If I had a single bulk api, I just could do with a single request.

Comment: Well, you have to detail your use case a little bit more otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Val Okay. Now that you have understood my requirement, what would you suggest ?

Comment: still the same :-) index templates are meant exactly for that purpose. Even if the settings/mappings change frequently, you simply update the index templates when that happens and the next index to be created will have the new settings/mappings. I'm still curious why those settings/mappings change that frequently though.

Comment: @Val Well,thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't work in my case. I agree that in some cases, index templates are useful. But in my case, each index name and settings are distinct. So,for me, there is no difference between updating the templates and creating new indexes. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's why I asked you to describe your use case. You just said that you had 100 indexes, not that all of them had different names ;-) Help us help you!

Comment: @Val I have mentioned it in my 3rd comment: `I will have to create multiple templates because indexes are very distinct` . In the context, I guess it explains the `distinct name` scenario as well.  But, I agree that I should have pointed that out separately. And I have also now updated my question with that info.